# making prime number in python but getting error in printing the else statement

Tags: python

I'm making program to check whether it is prime or not. But the else statement is not working.

```
val = int(input("Enter Number here"))
if (val % 2 == 0):
    print("Not Prime")

elif (val % 2 != 0):
    for i in range(3, val, 2):
            if (val % i == 0):
                print("Not Prime")
else:
    print("Prime")
```

also if I try removing the else statement with elif(val != 0) , there is no output

Comment: If you're getting an error, please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Your else will never be used where it is. The remainder is either 0 or 1 and the first two will cover that

Comment: You would get the error because either `val % 2 == 0` or `val % 2 != 0`. So you will never get to the else. So delete the else.

Comment: so when I replace else with elif I get an invalid syntax error

Comment: so what to do in that case @Buckeye14Guy

Comment: Don't replace the else. Just remove it. You need to understand the Maths and Logic behind your code before you begin programming. Let's assume `val % 2` is x. Then your code is `if x==0 do this, else if x!=0 do that`. Why would you then have another else. Either x is 0 or it isn't. Obviously, the `else` should be indented further in, so that it belongs to the inner `if` block.

Comment: @Vishal1809 your logic is that if all the values from your `for` loop are exhausted then the number is prime. I have an answer there. Make use of the `for ... else` statament

Comment: why did you down voted. I just started learning programming

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think you want your else right after all the `i` have been used. It is possible to use an `else` statement right after a `for` loop

```py
val = int(input("Enter Number here"))
if (val % 2 == 0):
    print("Not Prime")

elif (val % 2 != 0):
    for i in range(3, val, 2):
        if (val % i == 0):
            print("Not Prime")
            break
    else: # this else is not needed if the break is used above
        print("Prime")
```

Comment: I can't make an edit of less than 6 chars but the else block should be indented further to align with the if. Assuming based on your comment on the original question, that was the intended answer, just slightly misformatted

Comment: @ekmcd if it was indented then after the first iteration the number will come out as 'Prime' which is not actually what the original question asked. Take 25 for example. In the for loop, `25 % 3` won't be 0 but that does not mean that 25 is prime. The code the OP had is supposed to go through all odd numbers from 3 to the input and only after that conclude that it is prime since it was not divisible by any number below it

Comment: I apologize! You're totally correct. I had never seen the for else before so it threw me off and I (wrongly) assumed it was just an indentation error. As a math nerd I'm embarrassed I didn't think of the problem context! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to work around the logic problem is by storing the result in a variable and checking that variable right at the very end:

```
val = int(input("Enter Number here: "))
prime = True
if val % 2 == 0:
  prime = False
else:
  for i in range(3, val, 2):
    if val % i == 0:
      prime = False
      break

if prime:
  print("Prime")
else:
  print("Not prime")
```

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that you just need to check numbers up to the square root of val, not val to see if it is prime. This will make your code more efficient.

Some answers also fail the case val=1, 2 and other such cases.

Here is a correct solution:

```py
val = int(input("Enter Number here: "))
prime = True
if val==1:
    prime=False
elif val % 2 == 0 and val!=2:
  prime = False
else:
  for i in range(3, int(val**(1/2))+1, 2):
    if val % i == 0:
      prime = False
      break

if prime:
  print("Prime")
else:
  print("Not prime")
```